# Installing Developed Application into iphone device

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-3.x

Can anybody help me to install my developed app into an device.
what are the steps to execute my application in device.
how can i connect the device to run my application in device????

Please help me out.

Thank you..

Comment: have you developer profile to install on your device?

Answer (score 7):

## Creating ad-hoc distribution profiles

The instructions that Apple provides are not very concise or clear. This is how I created a general provisioning profile that will work with multiple apps, and added a beta tester.

My setup:

Before you get started, make sure that..

- You can run the app on your own iPhone through Xcode.

### Step A: Add devices to the Provisioning Portal

1. Send an email to each beta tester with the following message:

   > To get my app on onto your iPhone I need some information about your phone. Guess what, there is an app for that!
   >
   > Click on the below link and install and then run the app.
   >
   > http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=285691333&mt=8
   >
   > This app will create an email. Please send it to me.
2. Collect all the UDIDs from your testers.
3. Go to the [Provisioning Portal](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action).
4. Go to the section **Devices**.
5. Click on the button **Add Devices** and add the devices previously collected.

### Step B: Create a new provisioning profile

1. Start the Mac OS utility program **Keychain Access**.
2. In its main menu, select **Keychain Access  / Certificate Assistant / Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority...**
3. The dialog that pops up should aready have your email and name it it.
4. Select the radio button **Saved to disk** and Continue.
5. Save the file to disk.
6. Go back to the [Provisioning Portal](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action).
7. Go to the section **Certificates**.
8. Go to the tab **Distribution**.
9. Click the button **Request Certificate**.
10. Upload the file you created with Keychain Access: **CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest**.
11. Click the button **Aprove**.
12. Refresh your browser until the status reads **Issued**.
13. Click the **Download button** and save the file **distribution_identify.cer**.
14. Doubleclick the file to add it to the Keychain.
15. Backup the certificate by selecting its *private key* and the **File / Export Items...**.
16. Go back to the [Provisioning Portal](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action) again.
17. Go to the section **Provisioning**.
18. Go to the tab **Distribution**.
19. Click the button **New Profile**.
20. Select the radio button **Ad hoc**.
21. Enter a profile name, I named mine *Evertsson Common Ad Hoc*.
22. Select the app id. I have a common app id to use for multiple apps: *Evertsson Common*.
23. Select the devices, in my case my own and my tester's.
24. Submit.
25. Refresh the browser until the status field reads **Active**.
26. Click the button **Download** and save the file to disk.
27. Doubleclick the file to add it to Xcode.

### Step C: Build the app for distribution

1. Open your project in Xcode.
2. Open the *Project Info* pane: In **Groups & Files** select the topmost item and press **Cmd+I**.
3. Go to the tab **Configuration**.
4. Select the configuration **Release**.
5. Click the button **Duplicate** and name it **Distribution**.
6. Close the Project Info pane.
7. Open the *Target Info* pane: In *Groups & Files* expand *Targets*, select your target and press **Cmd+I**.
8. Go to the tab **Build**.
9. Select the *Configuration* named **Distribution**.
10. Find the section **Code Signing**.
11. Set the value of **Code Signing Identity / Any iPhone OS Device** to **iPhone Distribution**.
12. Close the Target Info pane.
13. In the main window select the *Active Configuration* to **Distribution**.
14. Create a new file from the file template *Code Signing / Entitlements*.
15. Name it **Entitlements.plist**.
16. In this file, uncheck the checkbox **get-task-allow**.
17. Bring up the *Target Info* pane, and find the section **Code Signing** again.
18. After **Code Signing Entitlements** enter the file name **Entitlements.plist**.
19. Save, clean, and build the project.
20. In *Groups & Files* find the folder **MyApp / Products** and expand it.
21. Right click the app and select **Reveal in Finder**.
22. Zip the .app file and the .mobileprovision file and send the archive to your tester.

    > Here is my app. To install it onto your phone:
    >
    > 1. Unzip the archive file.
    > 2. Open iTunes.
    > 3. Drag both files into iTunes and drop them on the Library group.
    > 4. Sync your phone to install the app.

Done! Phew. This worked for me. So far I've only added one tester.

See [Installing developed application into iPhone device](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a developers account, iTunes, a Mac computer, and the iPhone.

Follow this tutorial:

http://mobiforge.mobi/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices